Select fields replaced by datepicker in Chrome and Safari (iPhone)
We detected a serious UX delay in our legacy AngularJS app for mobile users, that get trapped in the datepicker when selecting date of birth.
In PC we just have 3 select fields, and it goes much faster. Weirly enough, the mobile browsers will just convert the selects into a datepicker, without any indication from our code?
Any idea on how to avoid the datepicker just hijacking the selects on mobile browser?
This is how it looks like:
<div class="row" translate-cloak>
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
    <select
      ng-model="day"
      class="form-control input-md"
      ng-options="item for item in days"
      autocomplete="off"
    >
      <option ng-show="!day" value="">{{ 'day' | translate }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5 hidden-xs">
    <select
      ng-model="month"
      class="form-control input-md"
      ng-options="item.code as item.name for item in months"
      autocomplete="off"
    >
      <option ng-show="!month" value="">{{ 'month' | translate }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 visible-xs">
    <select
      ng-model="month"
      class="form-control input-md"
      ng-options="item.code as item.short for item in months"
      autocomplete="off"
    >
      <option ng-show="!month" value="">{{ 'month' | translate }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <select
      ng-model="year"
      class="form-control input-md"
      ng-options="item for item in [] | range:18"
      autocomplete="off"
    >
      <option ng-show="!year" value="">{{ 'year' | translate }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

